# Input field validation in ui_component magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have below code in my form ui component , but it is not validating number

```
<field name="fsa_eligible_position">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">FSA-Eligible Position</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">integer</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">fsa_eligible_position</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="validate_number" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Comment: What issue are you facing here?

Comment: The validation doesn't show Sir. I tried inputting a text on the textfield but it still saves although the data becomes 0 after saving. I wanted to stop it from saving instead rather than save it and turn it into 0.

Comment: did you ran setup:upgrade command after changes in code?

Comment: yes Sir. everytime I make changes, I run setup:upgrade just to be sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added wrong class for validating number. Change below code

**from**

```
<item name="validate_number" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

**To**

```
<item name="validate-number" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```